# Searching sub string value in Numpy Array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy-ndarray

First of all, I am  using "Python" and the latest Pycharm Community edition.

I am currently working on a user interface with tkinter which is requesting several values from the user - two string values and one integer. Afterwards the program should search through an Excel or CSV file to find those values. Unfortuantely, I am currently stucked on the first entry. I've created a numpy array out of the dataframe, since I've read that arrays are much faster when it comes to work with great data. The final excel/csv file I am working with will contain several thousands of rows and up to 60 columns. In addition, the enrty_name could be a sub string of a bigger string and the search algortihm should find the fraction or the full name ( example: entry: "BMW", in array([["BMW Werk", "BMW-Automobile", "BMW_Client"], ["BMW Part1", "BMW Part2", "XS-12354"]) ). Afterwards I would like to proceed with other calculations based on the values in the array.

Example: entry: "BMW", in array([["BMW Werk", "Car1", "XD-12345"], ["BMW Part1", "exauster", "XS-12354"]])

Program found "BMW Werk" and "BMW Part1" in array, returns ["BMW Werk", "Car1", "XD-12345"] and ["BMW Part1", "exauster", "XS-12354"]

```
entry_name = "BMW"
   

path_for_excel = "D:\Python PyCharm\Tool\Clientlist.xslx"
client_list_df= pd.read_excel(path_for_excel , engine="openpyxl")
client_list_array= client_list_df.to_numpy()

#first check if entry_name is populated ( entry field in ui )

if entry_name == True:
    #search for sub string in string
    part_string_value = np.char.startswith(client_list_array, entry_name)
    if part_string_value in client_list_array:
        index = np.where(client_list_array == part_string_value)
        #print found value, including the other values in the list
        print(client_list_array[])
```

I am able to retrieve the requested values if the client is using the correct, full name like "BMW Werk", but any typo will hinder the process and it is very exausting for some names to type the full name, as an example one name looks like: "BMW Werk Bloemfontein, 123-45, Willows".

Hopefully, somebody finds time to help with my issue.
Thank you !

Comment: I recommend breaking this question into multiple new questions that are more specific and shorter. This will help people be able to provide answers to one specific problem